# Style Android RatingBar stars without icons

Tags: android, styles, themes, ratingbar

I have a RatingBar in Android application on which the stars take the primary color of the application. When I try to extend and change the colors like in this example from [here](http://www.materialdoc.com/rating-bar/) it doesn't have any effect.

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">  
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item></style>
```

Is there a way to customize this colors without setting `progressDrawable`

Here is the result with the primary color.

[image]

EDIT found the issue. I was trying the following lines

```
theme="@style/RatingBar"
```

or

```
style="@style/RatingBar"
```

but instead this should be used where I have forgotten the `android` keyword

The correct usage solved my issue:

```
android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
```

Comment: Show me how you use this rating bar style in your xml?

Comment: @BhavdipSagar Could you please add an answer, because your hint gave me an idea to find the issue. I have updated the question and wrote what was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.In your build.gradle add a latest app compact library.

```
dependencies {  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:X.X.X' // where X.X.X version
}
```

2.Make your activity extend android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    ...
}
```

3.Declare custom style in your styles.xml file.

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">  
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item></style>
```

4.Apply this style to your RatingBar via android:theme attribute.

```
   <RatingBar  
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:rating="3"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```